# Calculating repetitive fields using ModelBuilder of ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-pro, field-calculator, modelbuilder

I have a repetitive task that I wish to automate or make easier.

I have a table in a shapefile that has multiple fields, all starting "SignalV", SignalV0, SignalV1, SignalV2, etc.

[image]

I want to apply the following formula to each successive field:

```
V0 = SignalV1*((100-SignalV0)/100)+SignalV0
V1 = SignalV2*((100-V0)/100)+V0
V2 = SignalV3*((100-V1)/100)+V1
```

and so on.  This file may have as little as four fields or can have as many as 32 fields.  Also there are additional fields that are the result of Union functions.

Is there a different way to do this without having to "Add Field", "Calculate Field", manually type in formula, and continue onto next field?

It is tedious and prone to mistakes.

I have tried to put this into ModelBuilder but keep running into roadblocks.

Comment: I would use ArcPy and an Update Cursor.

Comment: As @PolyGeo hints this is quite possible in arcpy and python. If you are looking for a model builder approach consider exploring the [Field Iterator](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/modelbuilder-toolbox/iterate-fields.htm) using a wildcard to limit fields.